# Long accumulator instead of Double in MongoDB group() function

Tags: java, mongodb, double, long-integer

I am using MongoDB via official Java API. I can store and retrive Long values without any extra effort. But when I try to accumulate these values using `group()` function, JavaScript interpreter converts everything into Doubles and the final result ends up being a Double.

Here is my group command:

```
{
    ...
    initial: { count: 0 },
    reduce: "function (o, a) { a.count += o.count; }"
}
```

Is there a way to tell the interpreter that `count` is in fact a Long? Something like `count: 0L` or `count: Long(0)`? Or should I do the accumulation on Java side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because group command actually run map/reduce, and map/reduce is a javascript. In the javascript default number type is a double, because of this it return doubles.

So you can probably wrap your numbers with `NumberLong(..)` if you wanna see long in group command result:

```
{
    ...
    initial: { count: new NumberLong(0) },
    reduce: "function (o, a) { a.count += new NumberLong(o.count); }"
}
```

Not tested this, but almost sure that it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately `NumberLong` didn't work: "`ReferenceError: NumberLong is not defined`". It's odd because MongoDB documentation itself mentions it: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Data+Types+and+Conventions

Comment: @EserAygün: Can you try to use m/r instead of group, and try it within mongodb shell, to identify where is issue, in driver or in mongodb.

Comment: Ah! It turns out that I have version 1.2.2 installed. That's probably why it didn't work. Thanks again!

Comment: @EserAygün: i am almost sure, 1.2.2 it is very very old version :). You definitely need to upgrade up to 2.0.2

Comment: Yeah :) It appears that NumberLong was first implemented in 1.3.2: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-357

Comment: Point of clarification: the `group()` command is implemented in JavaScript as at MongoDB 2.0, but it is *not* a Map/Reduce.  The naming of the `reduce()` function perhaps confuses this.  Source reference on github: [/src/mongo/db/commands/group.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/commands/group.cpp).

Comment: Is it better to use `NumberLong` in JavaScript, or cast the result to `Long` in Java?